# TLS browser capability checker

Tags: web-apps, security

Is there a web application that checks the TLS capabilities of the browser? At least

- supported protocols and versions
- certificates

It should create a detailed report of the results. There're good tools for checking [server configurations](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) but same tools can not be used to check browser implementation.

There would be two ways:

- an app to deploy on an own server
- a server that provides this as a service

Where the first option is preferred over the second.

Comment: What are you going to use the reports for? We [prefer questions](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) that contain objective requirements (check, but they're rather seen) as well as a goal to accomplish.

Comment: I use mike's toolbox https://www.mikestoolbox.net and https://www.mikestoolbox.org/ (I think there is some difference between those variants, but forgot the details)

Comment: What do you mean by "certificates" in the context of client capabilities? Are you talking about the rarely used feature of client certificates, or something else?

Comment: Maybe the requirement about certificates can be left out. I think it's more important, that the solution can be self-hosted..

Comment: @JensPiegsa If being able to host the solution on your own server is a primary requirement, then the question should have stated that at the outset - instead of leaving open the option of "a server that provides this as a service". To eliminate that option would fundamentally change the question.

Comment: @Iszi: It would be preferred, but not mandatory. The current absence of a proposal fitting this requirement shows that it's always good to have an option B. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go back to the [Projects](https://www.ssllabs.com/projects/index.html) page on the site for the [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) you linked, and you'll find that [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html) also has an [SSL Client Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) which provides a rather detailed report.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer to demonstrate how this tool is a good fit? For example, a sample report would help. See our [answer quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. I think the (maybe temporary) downvote comes from a software rec "quality guard" intended to encourage an update.